# Adding dynamic block to magento checkout

Tags: php, magento

Hello I was wondering if it possible to add *'dynamic'* block to magento checkout onepage. Under *'dynamic'* block I mean that when I proceed through checkout onepage steps and for example, I choose specific payment type then the block is shown, otherwise it's not seen at all.

I've reached as far as when I choose my custom payment method the block is generated and text is shown, but only if I add the block's name('***excellence2***') to my Onepage.php $stepCodes list:

```
   $stepCodes = array('billing', 'shipping',  'shipping_method', 'payment', 'excellence2', 'review');
```

***Is there any way to generate 'excellence2' block without adding it to stepCodes?***

Comment: you should add block through layout xml to specific section, in your situation to payment section.

Comment: I've added necessary blocks to xml file. Everything works fine when I add block name to $stepCodes aswell, but I'd like to know if there's a way to render the block without adding it to $stepCodes? aka I'd like to have the step invisible on checkout onepage unless I call out/need the step.

Comment: You may not have invisible step because of checkout module architecture. So you can create something like substep for some step using JavaScript for hiding/showing your blocks at some moment